# Air quality monitoring devices for a320

Tags: airbus-a320, bleed-air, air-conditioning

I looking for the air quality monitoring devices for a320. How do they look, where they located?
thank you for the help

Comment: Your question presumes that such devices even exist.  Do you have any evidence that they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far as I can tell, there are no passive or active air quality monitoring devices on the A320. The cabin air systems on modern airliners are designed against an air quality standard, and their performance is tested with equipment that is installed on the test aircraft for that specific purpose.

EASA published the [results of an air quality campaign test program in 2017](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/research-projects/easarepresea20144).

> In total, 69 measurement flights were performed between July 2015 and
>   June 2016 on 8 types of aeroplane/engine configurations. This included
>   61 flights on aeroplanes equipped with engine bleed air systems, and 8
>   flights on Boeing 787 which is equipped with electrical compressors
>   (‘bleed free’ system). For all flights, measurement equipment was
>   installed in the cockpit and in the cabin.
>
> The results show that the cabin/cockpit air quality is similar or
>   better than what is observed in normal indoor environments (offices,
>   schools, kinder gardens or dwellings). No occupational exposure limits
>   and guidelines were exceeded. Special attention was paid to
>   organophosphates, in particular TCP (Tri Cresyl Phosphates) with the
>   use of high sensitivity analysis techniques. Only traces of TCP meta-
>   and para-isomers were sometime detected in all aeroplane types, but no
>   ortho-isomers were detected.